# Curl POST not sending data

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to connect to an echosign api which used to work and now has suddenly stop working, I have tried debugging but can't seem to resolve it, this is my code

```
  public function get_access_token_get()
  {
    $echoSign = new EchoSign();

    $ch = curl_init('https://secure.echosign.com:443/api/rest/v2/auth/tokens');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($echoSign->echosign_creds));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

    $result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

    curl_close($ch);

    echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>"; exit();

    return $result->accessToken;
  }
```

Comment: Can you show us the response you are getting?

Comment: it's empty completely empty

Comment: Have you checked curl is enable on server?

Comment: yes i did and its enabled

Comment: Do you have errors enabled?

Comment: yes i have errors enabled ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors', 0); ini_set('error_log', dirname(__FILE__) . '/error_log.txt'); error_reporting(E_ALL); on top of the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65257/discussion-between-varun-sheth-and-madforstrength).

Comment: Is your server allowing output requests on port 80?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your curl code with other urls, and its working fine for them, then i tried to call your url with other curl methods and it gives empty response, so I believe you should check with the echosign support to see whats wrong.